# iOS Google Cardboard+Virtual Reality+360 Degree View

Tags: ios, google-cardboard, 360-degrees, virtual-reality

My product is completely video based, i need to play those videos 360 degree orientation and which plays like side by side. As in [VR](https://vr.chromeexperiments.com/) or
[Homido](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/homido-360-vr-player/id909196467?mt=8). Will look forward for any valuable response and suggestions. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can someone answer to this pls...

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: No, i dint get any solution. Just achieved playing normal video side by side. No VR.